# If f is continuous then is $ F(x):= Sup [f(t), a \leq t \leq x ]$ Also continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Claim

$f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous, then is
$ F : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Then is $ F(x):= Sup [f(t), a \leq t \leq x ]$ Also continuous.

Argumentation

My understanding of the question: The claim must be true, since the resulting function seems to be constant at most areas, except when we have a new peak.
Supposing we have the highest peak at the start, then we recieve a continues function, if we have a higher peak at the middle, then we should recieve a constant function until we reach this new peak, then we have to climb up, such that the new function looks like a ladder. howevr since f is bounded, this can not go forever. and the size of these ladder jumps must be finite, since as stated the function is bounded.

Assistance

Overall, how do we mathematically express this argument in a correct mathematical manner, assuming what i just wrote is of truth, thank you.

Comment: The function is clearly increasing. It suffices to prove that $\lim_{x \to t^-}F(x) = F(t)$. By EVT, $\exists c \in [a,t] / F(t) = f(c)$. If $c \in [a, t) \Rightarrow \exists \varepsilon > 0 / F(t - \varepsilon) = F(t)$. Then, $F$ is constant on $[t - \varepsilon, t]$. If not, apply continuity at $f(c)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can Observe two useful things:

OBS1: $F(x)\ge f(x) \forall x \in [a,b]$

OBS2: if $x \le y$ then $F(x) \le F(y)$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ then for the uniform continuity of $f$ in [a,b] it does exist $\delta \gt 0$ such that for every $x$ and $y$ in [a,b] such that $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and let $x \in I=[x_0-\delta,x_0]\cap[a,b]$
then

$f(t)-\epsilon \le f(x) \le f(t) + \epsilon \forall t \in I$

So $F(x) \ge f(x) \ge Sup\{f(t)|t\in[x,x_0]\} - \epsilon$ (*)

Since $x\le x_0$ you have that $F(x) \le F(x_0)$
and, also, you get this sequence of inequalities from (*):
$F(x) = Sup\{f(t)|t\in [a,x]\}\ge Sup\{f(t)| t\in[a,x_0] \} - \epsilon=F(x_0)-\epsilon$

With a similar argument when $x\ge x_0$ you can prove what you wanted to prove

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is about right, but we want to formalize that. A formal proof of continuity will rely on the *definition* of continuity, so let's try an $\epsilon\delta$ proof (though you may greatly abbreviate the proof if you already have some useful theorems in your utility belt).

But first recall form the definition of supremum that
$$ F(x)>y\iff \exists \xi\in[a,x]\colon f(\xi)>y.$$
In particular, if $F(x_1)>F(x_2)$ then there is a $\xi\in[a,x_1]$ with $f(\xi)>F(x_2)$, but there is no such $\xi$ in $[a,x_2]$. It follows that $x_1>x_2$ and there is a $\xi\in]x_2,x_1]$ with $f(\xi)>F(x_2)$.
Even more in particular (as if it wasn't clear immediately), $F$ is non-decreasing.

Let $x\in [a-b]$. Given $\epsilon>0$, we want to find $\delta>0$ such that for all $t\in [a,b]$ with $|t-x|<\delta$, we have $|F(t)-F(x)|<\epsilon$. Along the way, we will certainly want to use that $f$ is continuous. To allow us some reserve, we will but let $\epsilon'=\frac12\epsilon>0$ and know that there exists $\delta'>0$ such that $|x-\xi|<\delta'$ implies $|f(x)-f(\xi)|<\epsilon'$. Let us try $\delta=\delta'$ and consider arbitrary $t\in[a,b]$ with $|t-x|<\delta$.

- If $F(t)>F(x)+\epsilon'$, then by the above remark, $t>x$ and there exists $\xi\in]x,t]$ with $f(\xi)>F(x)+\epsilon'$. But then from $|f(x)-f(\xi)|<\epsilon'$, we see $F(x)\ge f(x)>f(\xi)-\epsilon'>F(x)$, contradiction. We conclude that $F(t)\le F(x)+\epsilon'<F(x)+\epsilon$ (thanks to our "reserve")
- If $F(t)<F(x)$, then $t<x$ and $f(x)<f(t)+\epsilon'\le F(t)+\epsilon'$. As $f(\xi)<f(x)+\epsilon'$ for all $\xi\in]t,x]$, we conclude $F(x)\le f(x)+\epsilon'<F(t)+2\epsilon'=F(t)+\epsilon$